# All the cases where 的 (de) can be used

Tags: grammar

I have learned 3 cases:
1. 的: possession
我**的**家 
2. 的: adjective + de + noun
我喜欢红色**的**杯子。
3. 的: after adjective
我的头发长长的。

Are there any other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also used for constructing relative clause, such as, 那个穿白衣服的人是老板。我喜欢妈妈做的菜。

Answer (score 1):

**When read [ de ]:**

1. Transform noun to adjective:

> 我**的**同学 my classmate
>
> 你**的**名字 your name
>
> 红色**的**苹果 red apple

2. Be used to form a structure without a central word:

(1)Adjective can be used as noun:

> 这是我**的** this is mine
>
> 菊花开了，有红**的**，有黄**的** The chrysanthemums are in bloom; some are red and some yellow.

(2)Express a situation, reason, a (impatient or negative) emotion etc.

> 瞧这日子过**的**！Look at the days going by!(the speaker are feeling angry or despairing etc.)

(3)something else has nothing to do with somebody:

> 你睡你**的**，外面的骚动和你无关 You go on sleeping. The disturbance outside has nothing to do with you.

(4)Some "symmetrical" uses

> 战争结束了，士兵们死**的**死，伤**的**伤 The war is over, the soldiers are dead and wounded.
>
> 和朋友去山里野营，大家吃**的**吃，睡**的**睡 Camping in the mountains with friends, eating and sleeping.

3. Express "I'm sure"

> 这件事我知道**的** I do know this thing

4. "AB的"

A and B have similar meanings.

> 老乡们沏茶倒水**的**，对我们很热情 The villagers poured tea for us and treated us with familiarly.

沏茶 is A, 倒水 is B, they all mean "give you tea to drink"

**The other three pronunciations are also commonly used:**

**When read [ dí ]:**

> ——他是对的 he is right
>
> ——**的**确 yes(answerer also think he is right)

**When read [ dì ]:**

It means the center of an arrow target.

> 目**的** purpose
>
> 无**的**放矢 shoot at random(means pointless)

**When read [ dī ]**

no special meaning.

> **的**士 taxi
>
> **的**哥 taxi driver
>
> 打**的** call a taxi

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtfulness, you’ve made my day!